# returning search results in a table using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to write search results in a table using PHP and AJAX but so far I have not been able to do so. Whenever I press the search button the page refreshes and I'm unable to debug. However when I remove the ajax request to the php file I'm able to determine that the values of "dienst" and "ziekte" are stored in the js file (it doesn't refresh as it should) but whenever I try to access the php file however this doesn't work anymore because it starts refreshing (all the code unver var request=....

The goal is: from a form I get 2 values ( "dienst" and "ziekte" ), I use these values to run a simple select query that should return a couple of rows. These rows should then be translated in tablerows in html as a search result.

The code:

`search.js` file:

```
$('#searchButton').on('click', function() {
event.preventDefault();
var dienst = $('[name="dienst"]').val();
var ziekte = $('[name="dienst"]').val();

var request = $.ajax({
    url: "ajax/searchresult.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { 'dienst=' + dienst + 'ziekte=' ziekte },
    dataType: "json"
});

request.done(function( msg ) {
  $('#searchresults').html(msg);
});

request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});

});
```

`searchresult.php` file:

```
<?php

 include_once("classes/Db.class.php");
 include_once("classes/Patient.class.php");

 if (isset($_POST['ziekte'])) {

  try
   {
       $patient = new Patient();
       $patient->Dienst = $_POST['dienst'];
       $patient->Ziekte = $_POST['ziekte'];
       $results = $patient->SearchPatient();

       while($r = $results->fetch_assoc()){
                      echo "<tr>";

                      echo "<td><a href='profiel.php?username=".$r["username"]."'>". $r["voornaam"] . "</a></td>";
                      echo "<td><a href='profiel.php?username=".$r["username"]."'>". $r["achternaam"] . "</a></td>";
                      echo "<td><a href='profiel.php?username=".$r["username"]."'>". $r["username"] . "</a></td>";
                      echo "<td><a href='profiel.php?username=".$r["username"]."'>". $r["leeftijd"] . "</a></td>";
                      echo "<td><a href='profiel.php?username=".$r["username"]."'>". $r["beroep"] . "</a></td>";
                      echo "</tr>";
      }
   }
   catch(Exception $e)
   {
       $error = $e->getMessage();
   }
 }

?>
```

The html file for the result:

```
<div class="page-tables">
<!-- Table -->
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="data-table" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Voornaam</th>
        <th>Achternaam</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Leeftijd</th>
        <th>Beroep</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="searchresults">

    </tbody>

  </table>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

the SearchPatient function

```
public function SearchPatient()
    {

            $db = new db('localhost', 'root', '', 'project');
            $res = $db->Search( "'" . $this->Dienst . "'", "'" . $this->Ziekte . "'" , "patient_tbl");
            return $res;

    }
```

the DB class:

```
function Search($dienst, $ziekte ,$from)
{
    //SELECT *, IF( dienst = 'Psychiatrie', 1,0 ) + IF( ziekte = 'ADHD', 2,0 ) AS score FROM `patient_tbl` ORDER BY score DESC
    $query = "SELECT *, IF( dienst = '" . $dienst . "', 1,0 ) + IF( ziekte = '" . $ziekte . "', 2,0 ) AS score  FROM `" . $from . " ORDER BY score DESC";

        $this->last_query = $query;

    if($this->mysqli->query($query))
    {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: what does your $patient->SearchPatient(); look like?

Comment: It is just a simple select function for my DB... that should return some rows of users. I'll update my post with it!

Comment: what do you get if you put console.log(msg) in your request.done function?  are there any results?

Comment: i can't check because for some reason my page keeps refreshing. When Only after removing the var request code it stops the refreshing. `var request = $.ajax({
    url: "ajax/searchresult.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { 'dienst=' + dienst + 'ziekte=' ziekte },
    dataType: "json"

 });`

Comment: I think part of the problem is that your calling the searchresults.php file and expecting that to show you the table.  With ajax it should only return some data, and then you should be showing your table on your html page.

Comment: Even when I return a static data, it still wont stop refreshing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In search.js the $.ajax data should either be a query string ( data: { 'dienst=' + dienst + '**&**ziekte=' ziekte } ) or an object ( data: { dienst**:**dienst, ziekte**:**ziekte }, )